# Specific Page Won't Update

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm making an app in the Cloud9 IDE using Node.js with the Express.js framework. Something very odd is happening to a specific .ejs file where if I try to update it (like typing some mumbo jumbo in an h1 tag and then saving and restarting the server), it NEVER gets reflected in the browser no matter what I do. For example, if I delete my jumbotron, save, restart the server, and then refresh the browser, I still see the same page with the jumbotron. I also tried deleting this entire file and then restarting the server and I still see the page and it doesn't break my application which is bizarre. All other .ejs files are fine and I can see the changes that I make.

I've spent about 4 hours trying to figure this out and no one else seems to have my specific issue. I tried clearing my browser cache, using different browsers, logging in/out from Cloud9, creating a new database, going back to older versions of my code, etc. and nothing seems to be working. I'm not even sure what code to post on here since my entire app is about 2000 lines of code so far. Does anyone have any suggestions because this is really frustrating.

Comment: Are you using a build system? Something like grunt?

Comment: @HeadCode I'm not sure what that means. Here are all the tools I'm using: 1. IDE: Cloud9;  2. FRAMEWORKS: Express.js (w/ NPM packages),
Bootstrap; 3. SERVER TECHNOLOGY: Node.js; 4. LANGUAGES: HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript; 5. DATABASE: MongoDB

Comment: I'm running my application with "node app.js" so I am not sure if that counts as a build system.

Comment: I have never used Cloud9, but are you completely sure that the content in question was actually coming from that ejs file? It's possible that the page that the ejs content gets embedded in still has the jumbotron code in it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HeadCode I am sure that the content in question is NOT coming from that ejs file because I still see the page even when I delete the ejs file. I also tried to recreate the project in separate directory piece by piece and I was still getting the complete ejs file even when I was saving and restarting the server. I just don't know why it's affecting only that one page. I'm not even getting any errors so I can't even post an error log so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back. I was able to "resolve" it by creating a separate workspace and redoing my project there. That's not really a viable solution, but if you've wasted over 4 hours then I suggest that as a last resort.